# Specify another Windows account than session one when using DBI::dbConnect() and MS SQL Windows Authentication?

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I am in a corporate environment.

I can easily establish a connection between R and a SQL database thanks to `DBI` and `odbc` packages this way:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  driver = SQL.driver,
  server = SQL.server,
  database = SQL.database,
  encoding = SQL.encoding
)
```

This implicitely uses the "Windows Authentication" method. However, the server that will have to run the above R code will not be using a Windows Account that has actually access to the MS SQL DB.

Therefore, I would like to know **how can I explicitely specify another Windows Account prior to or within the code above?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In other words, I would like to reproduce following behavior in R the following manual process (on a Windows session that uses credentials not allowed to connect to the SQL DB):

- SHIFT+right click on MSSSM,
- "Run as a different user",
- Enter Windows Account #2 (the one that actually has access to the DB),
- Connect to SQL DB using Windows Authentication (the #2 one, not the Windows session one which does not)

Hope the context is clear.

For obscure corporate reasons, creating a local SQL account is not possible. Otherwise, thanks to UID/PWD of DBI/odbc it would be theoritically straighforward.

Comment: I regularly use `dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver="..", server="..", database="..", uid="myuser", pwd="mypassword")` for authenticating using a different user. The use of `pwd=` in the function may not be desirable if/when deploying, in which case envvars or use of the `config` package is generally recommended.

Comment: This does not work with the type of account we have. I think this is the difference between a "local" SQL account (uid/pwd would work) and a Windows service account that has SQL rights to connect (Windows Authentication).

Comment: Okay, it was worth a shot.